# Email validation is not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I have written code to perform email validation and password validation, but it is not returning any error if condition is not satisfied, didn't get any idea what is wrong with my code.

code in validation.js file

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');
 
exports.signupValidation = [
    check('name', 'Name is requied').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail().normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: true }),
    check('password', 'Password must be 6 or more characters').isLength({ min: 6 })
]
```

Code in router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db  = require('./dbConnection');
const { signupValidation, loginValidation } = require('./validation');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post('/register', signupValidation, (req, res, next) => {
// already return in validation.js file to throw error, what is the exact way to return error message
});
```

Comment: "but it is not returning any error if condition is not satisfied" — Which condition? For what input? If it isn't returning an error, what is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.post('/register', signupValidation, (req, res, next) => {
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({
        status: "failure",
        error: {
            message: "Invalid data to proceed",
            type: "ValidationException",
            code: 422,
            error_data: errors.array(),
        },
    });
}
next();
```

});

Comment: I didn't get why we need to call againvalidationResult(req) already we are checking validation in validation.js

Comment: Can u please explain little bit.